# Jquery selector with loop trying to obtain value not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a bunch of html elements and I would like to retrieve some elements and put them into arrays so I can retrieve them whenever I need. The problem is that the jquery selectors that I'm using is not working, the code seems to be okay and I wonder why I'm facing these problems. Could anyone help me ? Please run the snippet

```js
function grabData(){
   //trying to get all h5 tags into an array
 var count = $(".section").length;
 var questquest =[];
  
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  questquest[i] = $('.section h5').eq(i).val();
  console.log("questions = "+questquest[i]);
 }
  
   //trying to get all p tags into an array
 var count = $(".section p").length;
 var questP =[];
  
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  questP[i] = $('.section p').eq(i).val();
  console.log("Items = "+questP[i]);
 }
 

 
}

grabData();
```

```html
  
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 1</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 2</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 3</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm trying to get all the p into an array as well as h5.

Comment: `.val()` should be `.text()`. `.val()` is only for inputs.

Comment: You can also use `$(".section h5").each()` to loop over all those elements.

Comment: oh i didn't know that , what an idiot xD thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `questquest.push($('.section h5').eq(i).text());` and `questP.push($('.section p').eq(i).text());`. You can avoid using `questquest[i]` for assignment as `push()` is used to add a new value into the array and since it is sequential in your case use `push()`.

Furthermore, for the element `h5` and `p` use `text()` function to get the content of the element instead of `val()`.

```js
function grabData(){
   //trying to get all h5 tags into an array
 var count = $(".section").length;
 var questquest =[];
  
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  questquest.push($('.section h5').eq(i).text());
  console.log("questions = "+ questquest[i]);
 }
  
   //trying to get all p tags into an array
 var count = $(".section p").length;
 var questP =[];
  
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  questP.push($('.section p').eq(i).text());
  console.log("Items = "+questP[i]);
 }
 

 
}

grabData();
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 1</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 2</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <h5>Section 3</h5>
    <p>Stuff1</p>
    <p>Stuff2</p>
    <p>Stuff3</p>
    <p>Stuff4</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```